# Input focus scroll up above keyboard

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, cordova-plugins, ionic2

When I focus an which is positioned lower than the height of the keyboard, the input is getting hidden by the keyboard when I type its come above to keyboard

I am expecting the input to get scrolled up above the keyboard when i focus the input. someone suguest call this method in app.ts
[image]

```
declare var cordova:any;
declare var window:any;

platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // This requires installation of https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard
        // and can only affect native compiled Ionic2 apps (not webserved).
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
      }
    });
```

in my console shows cordova objects but not working when i focus on input the page scroll up, any solution i'am stuck on it

i referred [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/disable-scroll-ionic2-ios9-not-working/44847/5)

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11

Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20

Node Version: v6.2.1

Comment: Can you post your code in jsbin ? I have to check it. In the video, It is working fine. input is scrolled up and after the keyboard down, it is updated in the last input fields.